# ARAnchor position in 2D space

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, aranchor

So I am using `ARKit` and `ARAnchors` in an `ARImageTrackingConfiguration()`. I am using multiple versions of the same `ARAnchor` with different colored backgrounds. I would like to be able to get the background color of the `ARAnchor` being recognized (because if I register them all as `ARAnchors` it mixes them up even if they have different backgrounds). The way I was thinking of doing this was to get the position of the `ARAnchor` in 2D space and then obtaining the color of a pixel within the frame [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146557/how-do-i-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-a-uiimage-with-swift).

The problem is I can't find a way to get the `ARAnchor`'s position in 2D space. I am using a setup like below. If you have any idea how I can translate the coordinates or a better way to do this please let me know.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    
    let node = SCNNode()
    
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {

        if (anchor.name == "EXAMPLE MARKER") {
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "EXAMPLE")
            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
            
            // HOW TO CONVERT ANY OF THESE COORDINATE SYSTEMS TO GRECT? CGPOINT?

        }
    }

    return node
}
```

I've tried to get the position as follows but it always comes out as all zeros

```
print(anchor.accessibilityFrame)
print(imageAnchor.accessibilityFrame)
print(node.frame)
print(node.boundingBox.max,node.boundingBox.min)
```

Results

> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
>
> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
>
> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
>
> SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0) SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)

Comment: hi @Anters Bear , did you find any solutions to this?  i found this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861366/arkit-projection-of-aranchor-to-2d-space but it doesn't give accurate results.