# How can I reach 2D coordinate system from ARAnchor?

Tags: swift, arkit, aranchor

I'm newbee on ARKit and I searched lot of things to reach 2D coordinate system but I couldn't find anything.

I tried to use `lookAtPoints` to reach it. Here is my part of code.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor, let faceGeometry = node.geometry as? ARSCNFaceGeometry else {
        return
    }

         let lookAtPoint: simd_float3 = faceAnchor.lookAtPoint

         DispatchQueue.main.async {

             let currentSize = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.projectPoint(lookAtPoint, orientation: .portrait, viewportSize: self.sceneView.frame.size)

         }

    faceGeometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
}
```

When I run the app, the `currentSize` getting wrong values. What am I doing wrong in here? If someone can help me, I'll be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get an answer on this?

Comment: No, I'm sorry :(.

Comment: :( Thats okay!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ARKit - Projection of ARAnchor to 2D space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861366/arkit-projection-of-aranchor-to-2d-space)